# Magento 1 Admin panel a lot of problems please help

Tags: magento-1.9, product

We started to get a lot of problems in our magento admin back panel. 
The problem is that we cannot enter to products and to some of extensions. 
It simply loaded for several minutes and than going to nothing or to 504 time out gateway.

The guys of server says no any restrictions. "All ok from our side" 
The sucuri guys ( we use sucuri) also says that "all ok from our side" 
The front web is running excellent without any problem. Getting customers everyday no any issues with orders or checkout.

It simply not possible to make any change fron admin panel.

For example we installed the extension for google merchant feed. Also not possible to open it.

Some functions like "open customers, open orders, send tracking numbers are working without problem"

I asked from server guy to send the live error logs when I try to open any of products and see these errors

> [Thu Feb 28 06:22:13.022649 2019] [autoindex:error] [pid 30938:tid
>   47894805636864] [client 192.88.135.5:25599] AH01276: Cannot serve
>   directory /home/sextoyzone/public_html/media/: No matching
>   DirectoryIndex (index.php) found, and server-generated directory index
>   forbidden by Options directive
>
> [Thu Feb 28 05:59:02.148870 2019] [autoindex:error] [pid 16384:tid
>   47894818244352] [client 192.88.135.5:3703] AH01276: Cannot serve
>   directory /home/sextoyzone/public_html/media/: No matching
>   DirectoryIndex (index.php) found, and server-generated directory index
>   forbidden by Options directive
>
> [Thu Feb 28 02:40:47.701871 2019] [autoindex:error] [pid 30791:tid
>   47894826649344] [client 66.249.75.85:58755] AH01276: Cannot serve
>   directory
>   /home/sextoyzone/public_html/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/x200/040ec09b1e35df139433887a97daa66f/2/3/:
>   No matching DirectoryIndex (index.php) found, and server-generated
>   directory index forbidden by Options directive
>
> [Wed Feb 27 15:18:04.016345 2019] [:error] [pid 1727:tid
>   47838238512896] [client 192.88.135.5:8492] client denied by server
>   configuration:
>   /home/sextoyzone/public_html/master-series-crimson-tied-embossed-ankle-cuffs.html
>
> [Wed Feb 27 15:17:56.575693 2019] [:error] [pid 1727:tid
>   47838236411648] [client 192.88.135.5:6122] client denied by server
>   configuration: /home/sextoyzone/public_html/magebird_popup, referer:
>   https://www.sextoyzone.com/sexual-enhancers/female-enhancers/orgasm-sensitivity.html

Any help will be appretiate. Feeling stupid that cannot change my own product on my own online store... Weird situation.

Comment: What is your setup? A single server for frontend, admin and database?

Comment: Maybe you need to run compilation: "system -> tools -> Run compilation"